# Выделение памяти на локальные и глобальные переменные

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, embedded

В программировании встраиваемых систем не рекомендуется использовать динамическое выделение памяти. Отсюда у меня возник следующий вопрос. В случае глобальных переменных, на сколько я знаю, память выделяется сразу. Что делать с локальными? Компилятор сразу выделяет и на них память или возможна такая ситуация, что при вызове функции с локальными переменными, память МК будет переполнена, что вызовет печальные последствия?

Comment: Не путайте область видимости и классы памяти. Локальная переменная может быть объявлена как static. Тогда память под неё выделится сразу в статической памяти, а не на стеке.

Comment: Добавлю ремарку: утверждение "В программировании встраиваемых систем не рекомендуется использовать динамическое выделение памяти." - чересчур сильно. Спектр embedded systems очень широк и вовсе не ограничен "микроконтроллерами с 1К ОЗУ" и "бортовыми компьютерами ПКР", которые этим утверждением неявно подразумеваются..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Компилятор не может "сразу" выделять память под локальные автоматические переменные, ибо при каждом рекурсивном входе в одну и ту же функцию она должна получать новый, независимый набор автоматических переменных. Это требует *стекообразного* динамического распределения памяти для локальных переменных во время выполнения. Что, разумеется, может приводить и к переполнению памяти во время выполнения.

Если запретить рекурсивные вызовы в языке, то теоретически компилятор будет в состоянии предсказать максимальный вариант потребления памяти локальными переменными и даже выполнить "раннее" распределение памяти для таких переменных еще на этапе компиляции, фактически заменив их на глобальные переменные. Но что-то подобное можете сделать и вы сами, отказавшись от использования локальных переменных вообще.

(Хотя даже в таком случае компилятору будет проще обеспечить максимальную экономию памяти путем "совместного использования" одних и тех же областей памяти теми локальными переменными, которые заведомо не могут существовать одновременно. Выполнить такую "упаковку" переменных вручную теоретически можно, но задача это тяжелая, трудноподдерживаемая и чреватая ошибками.)

Answer (score 3):

Да, это запросто - потому что локальные переменные выделяются в стеке, и его можно переполнить.

Особенно при рекурсии или просто глубокой вложенности функций.

Так что нужно или очень строго контролировать, что вызывается и как, и чего и сколько выделяется на стеке, или... С другой стороны, локальные переменные - если их немного - позволяют не заботиться о возможных неприятностях типа перекрытия имен и т.п.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*